# Postgres pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, corruption, jackrabbit

My automated pg_dump process has been failing when attempting to backup a postgres database.  The error message I'm receiving:

ERROR Message:

> pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  invalid memory alloc
>   request size 1249770967 pg_dump: The command was: COPY
>   public.data_store (id, length, last_modified, data) TO stdout;
>   Custom backup of jackrabbit pg_dump: SQL command failed pg_dump: Error
>   message from server: ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size
>   1249770967 pg_dump: The command was: COPY public.data_store
>   (id, length, last_modified, data) TO stdout; [!!ERROR!!] Failed to
>   produce custom backup database jackrabbit Plain backup of pdi_logging
>   Custom backup of pdi_logging Plain backup of postgres Custom backup of
>   postgres Plain backup of quartz Custom backup of quartz

Based on my findings everything seemed to point to corrupt data in the table so I created a function to query the table and extract the ctid so I then may find the culprit and delete the corrupt row.

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_bad_row(tablename text)
 RETURNS tid AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
result tid;
curs REFCURSOR;
row1 RECORD;
row2 RECORD;
tabName TEXT;
count BIGINT := 0;
BEGIN
SELECT reverse(split_part(reverse($1), '.', 1)) INTO tabName;

OPEN curs FOR EXECUTE 'SELECT ctid FROM ' || tableName;

count := 1;
FETCH curs INTO row1;

WHILE row1.ctid IS NOT NULL LOOP
result = row1.ctid;

count := count + 1;
FETCH curs INTO row1;

EXECUTE 'SELECT (each(hstore(' || tabName || '))).* FROM '
|| tableName || ' WHERE ctid = $1' INTO row2
USING row1.ctid;

IF count % 100000 = 0 THEN
RAISE NOTICE 'rows processed: %', count;
END IF;
END LOOP;

CLOSE curs;
RETURN row1.ctid;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
RAISE NOTICE 'LAST CTID: %', result;
RAISE NOTICE '%: %', SQLSTATE, SQLERRM;
RETURN result;
END
$BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
 COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION find_bad_row(text)
 OWNER TO pentaho;
```

After calling the function `select find_bad_row('public.data_store')`, the result given was (0,2).  I searched the table for said ctid, `select ctid, * from public.data_store`, and deleted the preceding row.  I then executed my pg_dump script and received the same error. Re-running the function on the table returns a result again of the first row.  Being new to postgres is my approach altogether wrong and is there another way to resolve this?  Could it be that the entire table is corrupt?

Comment: Possibly none of your table is corrupt, it's just the rows that are too big to fit in 1GB of text. Can you share the entire output of the function, which should include notices and an error message?

Comment: The output only displays one column and row - "find_bad_row" and always produces the first CTID from the first row of the table.  I don't receive any error messages.  When trying to select * from the entire table which is only 9k rows I get this error, "lost synchronization with server: got message type "D", length 659014525", and I'm disconnected from the server.

Comment: Try `SET client_min_messages TO notice;` before running the function and if still not seeing the NOTICE output, switch to a SQL client like `psql` that has the capability to display them. This function issues `RAISE NOTICE '%: %', SQLSTATE, SQLERRM` when it gets any error with a row, and (I think) your really don't want to miss that error message in your case.